# Can a Small character with the Totem Warrior barbarian's Aspect of the Beast (Bear) feature use a heavy weapon without disadvantage?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, creature-size, barbarian, encumbrance

The Bear totem option for the Path of the Totem Warrior barbarian's Aspect of the Beast feature grants the following benefit if the Bear totem is chosen (PHB, p. 50):

> Your carrying capacity (including maximum load and maximum lift) is
>   doubled, and you have advantage on Strength checks made to push, pull,
>   lift, or break objects.

If my Halfling barbarian takes the Path of the Totem Warrior and chooses the Bear totem at 6th level, can he wield a heavy weapon due to his carrying capacity doubling?

I'm not too familiar with how size mechanics and carrying capacity fit together.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the *Player's Handbook*, page 147, in the descriptions of weapon properties:

> ***Heavy.*** **Small creatures** have disadvantage on attack rolls with heavy weapons. A heavy weapon’s size and bulk make it too large for a Small creature to use effectively.

Carrying capacity has no effect on your ability to use heavy weapons without disadvantage. That's determined solely by your size, and since this effect doesn't change your size; no, you still can't wield those weapons effectively.