# For a Small race using a heavy weapon, does the Enlarge spell remove disadvantage on attacks with it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, weapons, creature-size

The heavy [weapon property](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties) is described as follows:

> A heavy weapon’s size and bulk make it too large for a Small creature to use effectively.

And in the description of the Enlarge option of the [*enlarge/reduce*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enlarge-reduce) spell, it states the following

> The target's weapons also grow to match its new size.

This implies that the weapon grows along with the target, and thus the weapon would still be too large to wield.

I could not find anything on large weapons other then heavy weapons giving disadvantage on attacks when wielded by Small creatures.

So does *enlarge* remove the disadvantage from the heavy weapon? Or does the weapon grow with you and then would still be to big to wield?

Comment: The *heavy* property is so weird. It seems to arbitrarily punish small martial characters, without adding anything to the game.

Comment: Related: [Is there anything that cancels out Small creatures' disadvantage to attack when using Heavy weapons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113798/is-there-anything-that-cancels-out-small-creatures-disadvantage-to-attack-when)

Comment: @GreySage I think it's perfectly reasonable to model the limits that a Small sized creature would have on those weapons. It adds realism. It also creates incentives to use buffs to overcome the limitation, which burns resources, which makes things appropriately challenging.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### *Enlarge* removes the disadvantage.

The *[heavy](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties)* property only gives disadvantage to Small creatures.

> **Heavy.** Small creatures have disadvantage on attack rolls with heavy
>   weapons. A heavy weapon's size and bulk make it too large for a Small
>   creature to use effectively.

A Small creature that has been enlarged by the *[enlarge/reduce](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enlarge-reduce)* spell is no longer Small; it is Medium.

> This growth increases its size by one category—from Medium to Large,
>   for example.

Therefore the creature is no longer subject to the disadvantage granted by the *heavy* property.

Regarding the statement "The target's weapons also grow to match its new size"—the weapon may grow, but still has just the *heavy* property, which only affects Small creatures. The weapon gains no new property that grants disadvantage to Medium creatures.

If this bothers you, you can always reason that "to match its new size" means that the weapon becomes the appropriate size for a Medium creature.